# intellij idea reports cannot autowire beans for custom spring-boot-starter module

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I have 2 starter modules: spring-boot-starter-vertx & spring-boot-starter-vertx-consul

consul starter depends on vertx starter

Intellij idea reports it cannot autowire Vertx bean for consul starter module (it's defined in vertx starter module)

But all modules build & run successfully by maven(include the module uses vertx & consul starters)

How to tell idea the Vertx bean is provided by another module to avoid the error report? (i've added ConditionalOnBean but the error remains)

Answer (score 2):

resolved with @Import(VertxConfiguration.class) on ConsulConfiguration

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to define dependency of module in Intellij Idea. In this way Intellij build module in predefined order and set them in class path.

for more information:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html#working-with-module-dependencies

Comment: i tried to define the two configurations in one module and idea still report this error...

Comment: by the way, the module dependency already exists(managed by maven)

Comment: @rainmanhhh build in Intellij is different from compiling with Maven, So defining dependency in Maven doesn't affect IDE build. When you define dependency order in Intellij, it know which module should build first and put in class-path of other module.